# How to Update Records for lightning-datatable that have not been committed yet in a screen flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-datatable, update, screen-flow

I am using a [lightning-datatable](https://unofficialsf.com/datatable-lightning-web-component-for-flow-screens-2/) for flow screen navigation where by a user loops through a screen flow to generate objects that are stored in a collection variable that are actually inserted at the end of the process. These created objects are displayed in a screen that prompts the user if they'd like to create more objects or if they'd like to proceed to submit their progress and create those records. This component has the ability to edit object values via the data table, and store the edited records in a separate collection variable. I am finding it difficult to be able to persist these edits due to the inability to consolidate the edited records with the pre-edit records, as the "update records" functionality requires the records to have been inserted and contain a system ID to update on. What would be a good solution path to explore to try and accomplish this goal?